# Extracting the body HTML and clean comments using PHP and Regex

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I want to clean the comments and some other garbage or tags from the `<body>` section in HTML using PHP and regex but my code not work:

```
$str=preg_replace_callback('/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/s', 
    function($matches){
        return '<body>'.preg_replace(array(
            '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/',
        ),
        array(
            '',
        ), $matches[1]).'</body>';
    }, $str);
```

The problem is that nothing happens. Comments will remain where they are or any cleaning to do, nothing happens. Can you help? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @mhall I figureout that my regex not work becouse of attributes in `<body>` tag. I use his code and update this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?=<body(.*?)>)(.*?)(?<=<\/body>)/s',
    function($matches) {
        return preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $matches[2]);
    }, $str);
```

This work PERFECT!

Thanks people!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3044080

Comment: Why do you want to clean out the comments?  You could use `DOMDocument` or another document parser to do this more easily.

Comment: Without talking about how not pertinent it is to use regex, I think your problem comes from the `<body>(.*?)<\/body>` part. By default, the "." doesn't include line breaks. You might want to replace it by `[\s\S]` ## EDIT: Nevermind, didn't see the "s" flag.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I want a simple way to clean up some things from HTML.

Comment: Works for me (PHP 5.5.14), but it drops the `<body>`/`</body>` tags as well. What string are you trying with?

Comment: @nomistic I know that explanation. There are things that can be used in regex.

Comment: @mhall i update my code, just add `<body>` in function.

Comment: I agree with @ExplosionPills here... RegEx is not good for parsing dom. Use a dom parser.

Comment: @EddieB I know but I want to avoid additional library

Comment: It is what it is... if you need the library use it. You wouldn't hammer a nail with a screwdriver... ;)

Comment: You could also fix the attribute problem by just writing `<body` instead of `<body>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Made a modification on the `preg_replace_callback` not to include the `body` tags and replaced `(.|\s)` with a `.*` in `preg_replace`. Also dropped the `array` syntax from that and added a `/s` modifier:

```
$str = <<<EOS
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
             Here is some <!-- One comment --> text
             with a few <!--
                Another comment
             -->
             Comments in it
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
EOS;

$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?=<body>)(.*?)(?<=<\/body>)/s',
    function($matches) {
        return preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $matches[1]);
    }, $str);

echo $str, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
             Here is some  text
             with a few 
             Comments in it
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your body tag have any class declarations or such, or is it just a plain `<body>`?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you making it too complicated? You don't need to jump in and out via a callback, since `preg_replace` will make replacements at every match:

```
$parts = explode("<body", $str, 2);
$clean = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $parts[1]);
$str = $parts[0]."<body".$clean;
```

Splitting the string into head and body excludes the head from substitution without a lot of messy regexps.
Note the `s` after the pattern: `'/.../s'`. This makes the dot in the regexp match embedded newlines along with other characters.

Comment: No becouse in <head> tag I need to keep some comments for browser switcher.

Comment: Oh, I see. But still it would be much cleaner to split the string in two with `$parts = explode("<body", $str, 2);`, substitute in `$parts[1]`, and reassemble with `$str = $parts[0]."<body".$parts[1];`